# Gitlab ci build jar

Tags: java, jar, gitlab-ci

I try a simple step in gitlab ci

```
jar-java:
    stage: build
    image: openjdk:latest
    script:
        - javac *.java -d target/
        - jar cf build/Main.jar target/*.class
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - target
            - build/*
```

The result is as follows:

```
$ javac *.java -d target/
$ jar cf build/Main.jar target/*.class
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/Main.jar11521148926419944790.jar -> build/Main.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:477)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:266)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1432)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.validateAndClose(Main.java:458)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:325)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1687)

Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
```

Does anyone have an idea what wrong?

Comment: The build folder doesn't exist. `- mkdir build`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Elliott suggested, the build directory was missing.